# How I deal with Visual Studio solution and project files in Git?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, workflow, versioning

I usually work with .NET using Git for versioning. In my team, we work in parallel and we often commit our code to integrate in the application. Everything is fine BUT the Visual Studio's solution and project files. We found two ways:

1. Never commit those files, everyone has his own
2. Include those file in the version system

Both ways have pros&cons, but basically we struggle every time we pull from central repo. Here some spare issues we found: (in parentesis, the reference to the above list)

- We have to include other's files in the project (1) or include our newest (2)
- If we work on different architectures (x86/x64) we have to manually change `.csproj` files (2)
- Same issues replied for references and NuGet packages

and so on. **Is there a proper workflow I can use?**

Answer (score 18):

Committing `.sln` and `.csproj` files is usually the best practice (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873854/6309)), but merging requires some attention.
See "[Why are my `.csproj` files getting messed up after a `git rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483596/6309)".

<del>`*.csproj -text merge=union`</del> (see below)
`*.sln -text merge=union`v

Or you can give up on `.csproj` and regenerate them locally [as in this tweet](https://twitter.com/JayRWren/status/273146689467060224).
Another reason to ignore those csproj files is if they are regenerated, as [in this context](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50187)

[yellowblood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312391/yellowblood) warns ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511959/net-git-how-i-deal-with-visual-studio-files/21511990#comment41339744_21511990)) about serious conflict issue with `csproj` file when used with the `merge=union` strategy.
That echoes the article "[Merge conflicts in `csproj` files](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/04/16/csproj-merge-conflicts/)".
That is why there is a [suggestion for VS IDE should support file patterns in project files](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351288/vs-ide-should-support-file-patterns-in-project-fil.html) (in order to *not* modify the `.csproj` file if one add a new `.cs` file that fits that pattern).

> It's been suggested that if Visual Studio sorted its elements first, that would help mitigate the problem.
> That helps reduce the incidental conflicts caused by Visual Studio's apparent non-deterministic sort of elements.
> But it doesn't make the issue of merge conflicts go away.

Comment: I many VS projects \*.suo files get generated as well. Add `*.suo` to your .gitignore file. Plus you want to add the bin/* files for each project to your ignore file as well. They are all binary files. Also add the `TestResults` folder if you use MS Test or another unit testing framework.

Comment: csproj should NOT have merge=union, it can cause really bad merges.

Comment: @yellowblood good point. I have edited the answer to make that risk very clear, and have added some links to support that recommendation (of *not* using `merge=union` for `.csproj` files).

Comment: File order is significant in .fsproj files, so sorting .csproj or supporting file patterns would just mask the issue.

Answer (score 6):

In our project we check these into version control. We started with the `.gitignore` from [github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and a simple `.gitattributes` file:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.cs diff=csharp
```

This is because the `union` merge strategy can actually be dangerous for these files, see [Merge conflicts in csproj files](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/04/16/csproj-merge-conflicts/) for details why this is not always safe and is probably not what you want.

You'll generally get merge conflicts every time but they're really easy to handle quickly in Visual Studio. An example case is adding a new empty project to a solution and committing it, then having multiple team members add different files to the project.

In theory you could have a custom merge driver defined that handles xml merges better, but I haven't seen that done by anyone else yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020-04-08 and my choice for this is mark `csproj` and `sln` files as `binary`, still trying to find a sturdy practice but it's still not existed.