# A file passes to modified after a git pull from a clean working dir

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-commit, csproj

I'd like to understand the following situation about my git repository.

I'm at **commit XXX** and I have a clean repos (nothing untracked/modified) aligned with the last commit on origin/develop.

My colleague has created and pushed with Visual Studio, a new **commit YYY** on top of the previous **commit XXX** containing among others a **project.csproj** file having 4 new lines.

Just after that I pulled from origin/develop and retrieved only the **commit YYY**.

Now, the **project.csproj** file and only this one appears modified and impossible to undo with `git checkout project.csproj`.

The difference with the modified **project.csproj** and the one on the **commit YYY** is that mine (the modified) has 4 less lines.

***My question is, since i have pulled the commit with those 4 new lines why they weren't took into account?***

`git clean, git reset, git clone` changed nothing.

If i `git stash` the file **project.csproj** is copied to a new stash instead of being moved.

My colleague went back again to his VisualStudio and the **project.csproj** was surprisingly still modified with 4 new lines. He added the file to a **commit ZZZ** and pushed it to origin/develop.

When i pulled the **commit ZZZ** everything went back to normal, and **project.csproj** isn't anymore in modified status.

The SHA generated on project.csproj (in **commit ZZZ** and **commit YYY**) with

```
git ls-files -s project.csproj
```

after checking out  is the same.

This situation is reproducible when I return to the **commit YYY**

Could someone clarify the situation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: VS bug most likely.

Comment: I don't use VS (so someone who does needs to provide a real answer) but it seems that `.csproj` files are controlled and maintained by VS itself and therefore should never be committed. See also VonC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21511959/1256452).

Comment: @torek, you confuse *.csproj and *.csproj.user, the latter contains user preferences. The first one contains the project structure, the files, the references,.... and must be committed.

Comment: As I said, I don't actually *use* VS. I am merely relaying others' recommendations. If these files are XML, Git cannot merge them correctly.